# how to check reach and response time from my website?

Tags: web, time, response

i have a few websites on servers around the world.
i want to find out how much time does it take from sending the request from my computer to enter the site until the site begins to load in the server, and how much time does it takes from the time the server ended the request until i see the result on my computer.
thanks,
yishai

Comment: More interesting maybe: Not just measurements from "your computer" but also from clients all over the world.

Comment: Are you looking for the word "ping"?

Comment: my problem with ping is that i don't know how much packets my request for the page is, so i don't know how to simulate that operation by ping

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To check from your computer, there's an excellent free tool called Fiddler (Windows only). It is great for any sort of HTTP debugging, and one of its features shows request statistics, which might help you. (Note that the results can vary depending on your location, connection, time of day and phase of the moon)

[image: Fiddler screenshot]

Comment: BTW, it is quite similar to wireshark isn't?

Comment: @yishai: No, not really. Wireshark captures all the raw data (down to the ethernet frames, not just HTTP) passing over the wire and reconstructs the protocols from them; Fiddler acts as a HTTP proxy (works with a higher-level protocol). Although I have used Wireshark to debug HTTP problems, Fiddler is a more specialized tool for the job (think hammer vs. screwdriver).

Comment: got it. just wanted to understand the idea behind the program. i've used wireshark in my first degree so i have some experience with it. i meant it is similar in the way it captures data. thanks again.